# Question on class interaction

Tags: c++, oop

I have classes like below

```
class A
{
 private:
   B b;
}

class B
{
private:
  C c;
  D d;

}
```

C and D are storage class which mainly contains structs and data structure. B wrap both of it together. I am wondering what is a better approach in getting data C and D or performing a function if I have an object A?

```
 For example:
 class A
{
 private:
   B b;
 public:
   B* GetB() { return &b;} 
};

class B
{
private:
  C c;
  D d;
public:
  C* GetC() {return &c;}
  D* GetD() {return &d;}
};

class C
{
 public:
  functionA();
};


A a;
B* b = a.GetB();
C* c = b->GetC();
c->functionA();
```

OR

I shouldn't expose the object B at all:

```
 class A
{
 private:
   B b;
 public:
   C* GetC() { return &b.GetC();} 
   D* GetD() { return &b.GetD();}
};

A a;
C* c = a.GetC();
c->functionA();
```

OR

I shouldn't expose object B, C and D

```
 class A
{
 private:
   B b;
 public:
   void performFunctionA() { b.performFunctionA(); }
};

class B
{
private:
  C c;
  D d;
public:
  void performFunctionA() { c.functionA();}
};

class C
{
 public:
  functionA();
};


A a;
a.performFunctionA();
```

Why do we choose one over another?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Good encapsulation says that you should expose as little implementation detail as possible. In your case, that means favouring your last option and not exposing `B`, `C`, nor `D`. That way, any changes to `B`, `C`, and `D` can be insulated from `A`'s users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use the last option, if c have 10 functions and I need to access them all, in class B & class A, I need to add the 10 interfaces in both of the class. Woudln't that be a little bit of repetitive?

Answer (score 1):

I like your last option best.  Consider things from your users' point of view.  When somebody uses an `A` object, it's easiest if all they have to know is that they want to `performFunctionA`.  They don't have to know or care that an A contains a B which contains C and D.  Also, if you ever change the internal details of B, users of class A won't have to recompile.

If you do choose to expose handles to internal objects (as in your other examples), consider returning them by pointer-to-const or reference-to-const where practical.  That can help minimize the risk that a user will accidentally modify something that violates an invariant in one of the classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use the last option, if c have 10 functions and I need to access them all, in class B & class A, I need to add the 10 interfaces in both of the class. Woudln't that be a little bit of repetitive?

Comment: @leslieg, yes it would be.  You might ask why C is buried inside two different classes if it provides such a critical interface.  But often you're dealing with legacy code and you have no choice.  Personally, I'd rather get some good practice at my text editor's copy-and-paste function than blindly expose internal member data.  The latter choice can much more easily lead to maintenance problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) says that

> - Each unit should have only limited
>   knowledge about other units: only
>   units "closely" related to the current
>   unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its
>   friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

The last options seems to obey this law and is the best in my opinion.

Regarding your question for exposing other methods of an internal class the wiki also says that

> A disadvantage of the Law of Demeter
> is that it sometimes requires writing
> a large number of small "wrapper"
> methods to propagate method calls to
> the components.

So in the end it is your call. If you need to expose a few method I find Law of Demeter appropriate. It provides good guidance. On the other hand if you think that you code becomes bulky then it is probably a code smell:-)